# (PHP) cURL GET with headers and authentication

Tags: php, curl, https, get

I have the following PHP script that it supposed to echo the value returned from the API:

```
<?php
$curlSES=curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_URL,’username:password -X GET --header "Accept: text/csv"  “example:9000/api/search/universal/relative?query=chiave%3A%20%222022-01-26_14:46%22&range=160000&batch_size=500&fields=ALERTID%2C%20chiave" | wc -l');
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

$result=curl_exec($curlSES);

curl_close($curlSES);

echo $result;
?>
```

unfortunately, nothing is returned, I believe it's because I need to assign authentication credentials and headers to variables, but don't really know how to do.

Comment: [`curl_error()`](https://php.net.curl_error) after curl_exec() if `$result === false`.
But the value given to  `CURLOPT_URL` doesn't look like a valid URL.

Comment: @Syscall The URL I've used in my question is an example, but the parameters sent via URL are not.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have pasted the command for the `curl` request on to the `CURLOPT_URL` option's value. Instead, you should set them using `curl_setopt()`

Try changing:

```
curl_setopt($curlSES,CURLOPT_URL,
            'http://example:9000/api/search/universal/relative?query=chiave%3A%20%222022-01-26_14:46%22&range=160000&batch_size=500&fields=ALERTID%2C%20chiave');
```

And, adding (before `curl_exec()`):

```
curl_setopt($curlSES, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/csv'
));
curl_setopt($curlSES, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSES, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username:password");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get infinite page load, while if I copy-paste the URL used in cURL in the browser I get "{"type":"ApiError","message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}"

Comment: @gigapico00 this issue is probably related to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @gigapico00 see updated answer. Try it now

Comment: Excellent, yeah the probably are, will do so more testing with the API. In my example I was appending " | wc -l" after the URL, but I was probably doing that wrong. May you tell me the correct way?

Comment: @gigapico00, right now, please try the edited answer. And let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: @gigapico00 try it now

Comment: What application are you running on port 9000?

Comment: I'm running Graylog

Comment: @gigapico00 try it now

Comment: What should change?

Comment: @gigapico00 remove the line containing '`GET`'

Comment: Tried with no success